# Can compression fittings for PE buried gas line be safely used without stiffeners?

Tags: natural-gas, pipe-fitting, burial

I have a 1" buried PE gas line that I'd like to tap into for a gas firepit.  The gas line supplies a few other things in the yard, notably a 400kbtu pool heater.  From research, it seems undersized for this load, so while the heater seems to work OK, my assumption is that I don't want to do anything to further reduce flow.

The easiest DIY approach is to use a compression fitting like this one:

[image: IPS compression Tee fitting]

My concern is that it requires stiffeners (white in this picture) be added to the ID of each end of the pipe, which will inherently limit flow a bit.  My question is:  Is it possible to use this type of compression fitting without a stiffener?

My fallback is to use fusion fittings, which do not reduce the ID but require the rental of a special tool and require some skill to get right.

Comment: Requiring some skill to get right and doing it the first time with gas, does not seem like the brightest of ideas.  The best idea seems to get a bigger pipe, if your pipe is at its limit.

Comment: Your assumptions about significantly reduced flow at these fittings, or indeed about sizing the pipe for your loads, might be incorrect. This seems like a good time to hire an expert to do an evaluation of your outdoor gas system. Depending on your location, you may need gas company and/or local city approval as well. They might have helpful suggestions.

Comment: Do not use them without the stiffener or the ID will be reduced even more, because the tube will be crushed; also, you will have a leak. If it were me I would use the compression fittings (with stiffeners) and forego using the fire pit and pool heater simultaneously, rather than dig up the entire pipe...

Comment: Are you using rubber hoses for the gas ? those fittings are good for that

Comment: Answering a few questions in one:

1)  Replacing 200+ feet of buried PE pipe with larger diameter, some of which is buried under hardscape, is not a viable option.

2)  It's not an issue of simultaneous use, rather that I'd be adding an orifice of sorts mid-line, potentially impacting heavy use appliances downstream (even if operated one at a time).

3) I'll hire an expert if I conclude that I need to, but I'm still at the phase of the project where I am determining if I'm capable of DIY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. One must follow the manufacturer's instructions for installation of fittings; here is a sample section from one:

[image]

According to the same manufacturer, in recent years many gas companies have upped the gas supply pressure at the meter, so you may have plenty of supply in a 1 inch pipe, but may also have to install an inline line pressure regulator. As they write, you need to contact your gas company to find out the exact situation for your supply.

[image]